# How do I trace a potential undefined behavior situation?

Tags: fortran

I get a double free error on deallocate, when the pointer is associated. I suspect some undefined behavior is ongoing, but I have no idea where to start looking for it, or how. How do you track down undefined behavior ?

The compiler is intel 12. I can't post code because it's huge, and I am not even sure the source of problem is in my code. It may be in a colleague's library. I tried to do some debugging with gdb, but I don't get very far. This is the error.

malloc: *** error for object 0x102302f20: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

The line immediately before that is a print *, associated(pointer), which prints true.

This is the backtrace

```
#0  0x00007fff9327b6c0 in malloc_error_break ()
#1  0x00007fff9327b805 in free ()
#2  0x0000000100d27470 in for_dealloc_allocatable ()
#3  0x0000000100506699 in sharedarraysmodule_mp_deleterealsharedarray2_ () at SharedArrays.f90:609
#4  0x00000001003bbc4e in gammaaggregatormodule_mp_deleteprivate_ () at GammaAggregator.f90:86
#5  0x0000000102300bc0 in ?? ()
Previous frame inner to this frame (gdb could not unwind past this frame)
```

Comment: With difficulty !  And a debugger (perhaps). Care to show us any code and error messages, what compiler are you using, the usual stuff ?

Comment: yes I am doing that. I post twice so I get a double kick on the queue

Comment: did you try `valgrind ./a.out`?

Comment: @Zhenya: I don't expect it to produce anything meaningful, except a huge backtrack due to the horrible way the code is written. Any signal is going to be drowned. I've already been there

Answer (score 4):

Long comment, might point (sorry, couldn't resist) towards an answer ...

To be pedantic, it looks as if your compiler's best guess is 'pointer being freed was not allocated'. But in Fortran pointers only have statuses `undefined`, `associated` and `disassociated` so the error message may arise out of calls to the system functions which the compiler links into your executable.

That being said, I'd look for:

- A target going out of scope while a pointer to it remains in scope.  The Fortran 2003 standard states (note 16.13)

  A pointer from a module program unit may be accessible in a subprogram via use association.
  Such pointers have a lifetime that is greater than targets that are declared in the subprogram,
  unless such targets are saved. Therefore, if such a pointer is associated with a local target, there is
  the possibility that when a procedure defined by the subprogram completes execution, the target
  will cease to exist, leaving the pointer “dangling”. This standard considers such pointers to have
  an undefined association status. They are neither associated nor disassociated. They shall not be
  used again in the program until their status has been reestablished. There is no requirement on a
  processor to be able to detect when a pointer target ceases to exist.

The same document also states that the association status of the pointer passed to the `associated` intrinsic *shall not be undefined* so it's probably allowable for the program to lie and tell you that `associated(undefined_pointer)==.true.`.

- An allocatable target being deallocated, either by going out of scope or as a result of  a `deallocate()` call.
- Pointers being nullified on declaration, eg `real, pointer :: rptr => null()` (this is generally held to be a good thing, you might look to ensure that your code conforms).
- Pointers being nullified before they have been associated, though I don't think that nullifying a null pointer is an error according to the standard.
- Pointers to pointers.

The error messages you report tend to suggest that you have a case of module variables going out of scope, but, as you've already observed, it's kind of difficult to be certain.

If this doesn't help, contact Intel tech support, I find them very helpful, they are pretty good at spotting problems in one's codes.